How to install PostgreSQL extension with Docker
I have Dockerfile:
FROM postgres:14.0

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        zlib1g-dev \       
        pkg-config \
        git \
        mc \
    && echo "2" | apt-get install -y postgresql-server-dev-all \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-gzip.git \
    && cd pgsql-gzip \
    && make \
    && make install

I use this file with docker-compose.yml and docker-compose up -d command. I get access to the database, but the CREATE EXTENSION gzip command gives:
SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/gzip.control": No such file or directory
How can I add the specified extension for Postgresql using Docker?

You are missing the clang-11 package to install, I added this package and postgresql-server-dev-14 also:
Dockerfile_gzip
FROM postgres:14.0

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        zlib1g-dev \       
        pkg-config \
        git \
        mc \
        postgresql-server-dev-14 \ 
        clang-11

RUN git clone https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-gzip.git \
    && cd pgsql-gzip \
    && make \
    && make install


and after docker-compose up -d commad using this docker-compose file:
version: "3"

services:
    pg14:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_gzip
        container_name: pg14-gzip
        ports:
            - 15566:5432
        env_file: pgsecrets.env

pgsecrets.env file
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="-A trust"

I was able to create the extension
docker exec -it pg14-gzip bash
root@98ceed5151c0:/# su - postgres
postgres@98ceed5151c0:~$ psql
psql (14.0 (Debian 14.0-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create extension gzip ;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# \dx
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 gzip    | 1.0     | public     | gzip and gunzip functions.
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)

postgres=# 

